# Calculate difference between two sets of dates and divide the results in Flutter

Tags: flutter, date, dart

I have four dates (date1, date2, date3 and date4).

I have a script that works out the number of days between date1 and date2 ('date1calc') - then works out the number of days between date3 and date4 ('date2calc').

What I now want to do is date1calc divided by date2calc to give me a value. We'll call this 'dateValue'. Although I get the correct values for date1calc and date2calc it displays dateValue as '0'.

Here is the code:

```
var date1calc = singleDate.difference(dateNow).inDays;
var date2calc = singleDate.difference(startSingleDate).inDays;
var dateValue = date1calc ~/ date2calc;
```

When I print out the values of all three, it shows:

```
date1calc = 140
date2calc = 270
dateValue = 0
```

Why is dateValue showing as '0' instead of '0.5185'?

Thanks in advance

**** Update ****

Thanks to edbond - that fixed the issue I had, and the console correctly displayed dateValue as 0.5185xxxxxxxx

This though left me another issue which was ''double' is not a subtype of type 'int'

To fix this - and in case anyone else stumbles upon this for an answer - I found another solution to turn the double in to an int:

```
double x = dateValue;
int a = x.toInt();
var dateValue2 = a;
```

By then calling 'dateValue2', instead of 'dateValue in to the rest of my code, it worked like a charm!

I can't say it's the 'best' way of doing this, but it worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using integer division ~/ instead of float division /

```dart
void main() {
  var date1calc = 140;
  var date2calc = 270;

  print(date1calc / date2calc);
}
```

prints `0.5185185185185185`

Comment: That fixed the console output - thanks!! .... it has triggered a separate error though in the Console which shows " type 'double' is not a subtype of type 'int' " .....I'm trying to investigate this further